# remove checkbox attribute in jquery clone

Tags: jquery, html

my script code and html is like this when i am trying to add new row it is automatically select property of last checkbox if chekbox is checked than in new row add checkbox with check want to remove checkbox checked in new row

script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});
</script>
```

table look like this

```
   <table id="table-data" width="100%">
                  <tr class="tr_clone">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" autofocus name="status[]" value="Y"></td>
                    <td>
                      <select name="group_id[]">
                        <option>Select User</option>
                         <?php
                           $selectGroup = "SELECT  group_id,group_name
                                              FROM `group`";
                           $res = mysql_query($selectGroup);
                           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
                           {
                             echo '<option value="'.$row['group_id'].'">'.$row['group_name'].'</option>';
                           }
                          ?>
                      </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><textarea name="address[]" rows="3" cols="35" placeholder="Enter Address"></textarea></td>
                    <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: Your explanation is incomprehensible. Also, please provide a small (trim *everything* which is not relevant to the question), simple example; ideally a complete HTML page one can test. Specifically, without PHP code in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check below code .  you can find checkbox from cloned element using `$clone.find('input[type=checkbox]')` and set `.attr('checked', false)`;

working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/o4L2gLoj/2/)

```
 $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
  var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
  var $clone = $tr.clone();
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $clone.find(':checked').attr('checked', false);
   // or 
  // $clone.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
  $tr.after($clone);
});
```

Comment: happy to help you . pls accept answer if it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `checked` property. Try with -

```
var $clone = $tr.clone().prop('checked', false);
```

OR

```
var $clone = $tr.clone().removeAttr('checked');
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x6os5pet/)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is code...**

```
 $("input.tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {

          var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
          var $clone = $tr.clone();
          var $clone = $tr.clone().prop('checked', false);
         //  or var $clone = $tr.clone().removeAttr('checked');

     });
```

This isn't new with jQuery 3: it was always the case that setting the checked property to false was better than removing the attribute. "In all other cases, .prop( "checked", false ) should be used instead." - I know you're quoting the jQuery people, but that's not correct either: you shouldn't say $(this).prop("checked", false) in cases when you can just say this.checked = false;